# Composer errors on installing phpunit/phpunit because of overriding MAXPATHLENGTH

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have a PHP project, with a folder structure like this:

```
C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Web_development\Projects\Back_end\Current\Project_name\Workspace
```

I've got composer installed for this project, and already installed some packages with it. My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Bas/Project_name",
  "description": "...",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Bas",
      "email": "..."
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "psr/log": "1.0.2",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.22.0",
    "ip2location/ip2location-php": "8.0.2"
  }
}
```

When I am trying to install the `phpunit/phpunit` version 5.7.x (latest) package, it gives me the `[ErrorException] ZipArchive::extractTo(): Full extraction path exceed MAXPATHLEN (260)` error. The full error message looks like:

```
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

Using version ^5.7 for phpunit/phpunit
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/environment (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (3.4.3)
    Downloading: 100%

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [ErrorException]                                                       
  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Full extraction path exceed MAXPATHLEN (260)  


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-autho
ritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I'm installing the package with the `composer require phpunit/phpunit` command.

I've done some research to this problem, and it is caused by having a to long directory structure, but when counting my current directory structure, it only has 87characters in it.

I've tried running the `composer install` and the `composer update` command with the `--prefer-source` parameter. This both didn't work and gave me the same error.

I'm currently running Windows 10 64bit.

How does this problem occur? since I have a directory structure under the `MAXPATHLEN (260)` variable.

Is there any way to solve this without changing my directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is long. Whether it is too long or not depends on the depth of the directory structure in your project.

Remember that using Composer will create sub folders. At least you'll create `vendor/phpunit/phpunit` (22 chars), and on top of this all the sub folders of PHPUnit itself. I found this path as an example: `src/Framework/Constraint/JsonMatches/ErrorMessageProvider.php` (another 62 chars).

Adding some more directory separators, we are at least 87 + 22 + 2 + 62 = 173 chars long. That's a lot more near the maximum of 260 than you thought.

Your problem appears when unpacking the mock object component. I found this interesting path: `tests/MockObject/Generator/namespaced_class_implementing_interface_dont_call_parent_constructor.phpt` - 101 chars. Combined with the vendor folder `vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects` (36 chars) and two more directory separators we are at 87 + 36 + 2 + 101 = 226 chars - getting closer to the maximum. Now you'd just need another 34 chars coming from anywhere, maybe there is a temporary file name created during unpacking, and you'd hit the limit.

Shorten your existing path, and it will work.

Comment: Does only Windows have this problem though? I need the longer directory path since i'm dealing with alot of files.